# Event id 4227 tcp/ip warnings on Windows 7

Tags: windows, networking, tcpip

We're deploying a new image out to the field, and we're seeing tcp/ip event id 4227 warnings periodically throughout the day (1-3 a day).

The event message reads as follows:

> TCP/IP failed to establish an outgoing connection because the selected
>   local endpoint was recently used to connect to the same remote
>   endpoint. This error typically occurs when outgoing connections are
>   opened and closed at a high rate, causing all available local ports to
>   be used and forcing TCP/IP to reuse a local port for an outgoing
>   connection. To minimize the risk of data corruption, the TCP/IP
>   standard requires a minimum time period to elapse between successive
>   connections from a given local endpoint to a given remote endpoint.

I created a script that listens for this eventid and immediately checks "netstat -ano".  The script summarizes what state the ports are in, but I don't see an immense amount of ports opened. Here's the output from the script:

> 50 ports in state LISTENING
>
> 3 ports in state TIME_WAIT
>
> 58 ports in state ESTABLISHED

I don't understand why such a small amount of ports would trigger the 4227 warning.  Does anyone have any insight into this?

PS> I've set the TcpTimedWaitDelay reg entry to 30 seconds a la [this link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/itmanagement/en-US/d770e9fd-53a2-4ae9-99b3-2754c4564592/tcpip-connection-issue-on-windows-server-2008-sp2?forum=winserverPN).  I've also configured the dynamic port range to be larger using these commands:

> Netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport udp start=35535 num=30000
>
> Netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport tcp start=35535 num=30000